# Seemingly equivalent method calls -- one works, one doesn't?

Tags: java, syntax, boolean, token

```
public class uhh {

public static void main(String[] args){
    //boolean[][] tester = { {false}, {true} };
    //testMethod( tester );

    testMethod(  {{false}, {true}}  );
}


public static void testMethod( boolean[][] testing) {
    System.out.println(testing);
}   

}
```

The commented out code runs, but the uncommented code creates the error: "Syntax error on token "testMethod", @ expected before this token"

Why is one working if the other one is going wrong? They seem identical to  me.

Comment: You can’t pass in an array like that.

Comment: You need `new boolean[][] {{false},{true}}` in the parameter list of the second one.

Comment: This isn't valid syntax. [Read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/)